# How do I set up the directories for a [processing.js] canvas using HTML5?

Tags: html, canvas, directory, html5-canvas, processing.js

So I have this project, and to actually start it I need to make a processing.js canvas using an HTML file. When I load my file in Chrome, the page says there is a canvas but it will not load the code.

The file is located as follows: `E:\Final Project\COLS-1100`

The HTML file is called `index.html` and is located directly in this folder. Also here are folders called lib and pjs. Pjs holds `game.pde`, the processing file. Lib holds the processing.js library, called `processing.js`.

The html code looks like this:

```
<!--COLS PROJECT-->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>-----------</title>
        <script src="H:\Final Project\COLS-1100\lib\processing.js"></script>
    </head>

        <body>
            <canvas id="gameCanvas" data-processing-sources="\Final Project\COLS-1100\pjs\game.pde"></canvas>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The `game.pde` code looks like this so far:

```
void setup() {
    size(400, 400);
    background(100);
};

void loop() {

};
```

I have the suspicion that my issue is simply that I have written my directories wrong.

Comment: 1) Do not use phrases like "I NEED THIS ANSWERED RIGHT AWAY" - We all do. This is more likely to put people off answering, than encourage them to. 2) If you have a suspicion, try it, if that doesn't work, tell us why not and the expected result before posting.

Comment: Sorry. Anyways, I tried to rewrite the directories but they still don't work.

Comment: I did some research, but the directories still don't work.

Comment: Use your browser's console to figure out what's not loading. Can it find the processing.js library? Can it find your pde file?